# Sqlplus not found in oracle docker mage

Tags: linux, oracle, docker, shell, dockerfile

I have a working oracle image, which I can use run then use docker exec to get into the running container and execute sqlplus command with no issue.

Now I am trying to create a new image with some initial data using this image. Here is my docker file.

```
FROM oracle:12.2

USER root

COPY /testingData /testingData

RUN chown -R oracle:oinstall /testingData
RUN chmod -R 755 /testingData

USER oracle
RUN /testingData/runInitSQLScript.sh
```

And here is my sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF
CONNECT sys as SYSDBA/testpass;

whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
set echo off
set heading off

@/sql/mytestingData.sql

exit;
EOF
```

It kept telling me sqlplus command not found

When I try to use the full path of the sqlplus like this `@ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus`, it still says the same. Then I tried to check on the path, I realize I can only get into one layer under the root directory, for example, if my ORACLE_HOME is `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/`, I can only `cd` into `/u01`, when I do cd `/u01/app`, it start to say that directory not found. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you image is similar to official images, it installs Oracle software and creates database only after the start of container. So at the moment when you create image, ORACLE_HOME directory doesn't exist yet.
In case of official images, I'd suggest you to put your scripts into one of these 2 special folders:

```
   -v /opt/oracle/scripts/startup | /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/startup
                  Optional: A volume with custom scripts to be run after database startup.
                  For further details see the "Running scripts after setup and on startup" section below.
   -v /opt/oracle/scripts/setup | /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup
                  Optional: A volume with custom scripts to be run after database setup.
                  For further details see the "Running scripts after setup and on startup" section below.
```

More about this: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance

Comment: This must be the reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**update:**
As per @Sayan comment the sqlplus exist on `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus` path.
OR

the other option is to use below docker image to connect with `Oracle database container`

```
docker run --interactive guywithnose/sqlplus sqlplus {CONNECTION_STRING}
```

or use legacy linking to better to use docker network

```
docker run --it --link db guywithnose/sqlplus sqlplus {CONNECTION_STRING}
```

Now you can use `db` as host name for db connection.

https://github.com/sflyr/docker-sqlplus

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I am not using the official image, I put the image name like that just make it easy to read. I can run this image and execute sqlplus in the command with no problem. It does have sqlplus installed.

Comment: All official images contain sqlplus in `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus`

Comment: All official images install sqlplus in `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus`. They just install all software and create database at startup, so you need to start container and wait when it's done

Comment: Thanks @SayanMalakshinov for the information.answer updated.